# dotnet run not working after update to dotnet 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I updated yesterday from .Net 5 to .Net 6 and now my projects can't start with `dotnet run`. I then get the error:

```
Building...
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer[5]
      The ASP.NET Core developer certificate is in an invalid state. To fix this issue, run the following commands 'dotnet dev-certs https --clean' and 'dotnet dev-certs https' to remove all existing ASP.NET Core development certificates and create a new untrusted developer certificate. On macOS or Windows, use 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust' to trust the new certificate.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer[4]
      The ASP.NET Core developer certificate is in an invalid state. To fix this issue, run the following commands 'dotnet dev-certs https --clean' and 'dotnet dev-certs https' to remove all existing ASP.NET Core development certificates and create a new untrusted developer certificate. On macOS or Windows, use 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust' to trust the new certificate.
```

I've tried all the steps to remove/clean and create again but that doesn't help. The server starts but no connection from a browser is possible.

I use Mac OS 11

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue that was resolved after running `dotnet clean` in my project before building and running again.

Answer (score 5):

Add `<UseAppHost>false</UseAppHost>` under the `<PropertyGroup>` element of your project file.
To learn more about this (hopefully) temporary issue, check out [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/22544)

#### 3rd pardy edit

To quote the link

> To workaround this issue the  MSBuild property can be set
> in the project file to false, e.g.:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <UseAppHost>false</UseAppHost>
</PropertyGroup>
```

> You can also pass this property as part of the dotnet run command
> itself: `dotnet run -p:UseAppHost=false`

Comment: Thanks a ton, that solved the same issue for me. Interestingly it worked the past weeks (i only started C# development a month ago) and broke after updating visual studio to the latest preview today ... for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete all the SDK's above 3.1.4xx as I am working on 3.1.x
Only after that the newly generated dev cert worked.

I will install SDK's later when I work on a newer dotnet core version.

MacOS location = /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk

MacOS version 12.3 Monterey