# Dotnet CLI command "dotnet run" simply quits

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, dotnet-cli

Environment: Ubuntu 20.04

MyApp: ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project

```
$ dotnet --version
6.0.100
```

After my recent OS upgrade, looks like dotnet sdk 5.0 got replaced with 6.0. I edited my MyApp.csproj file and changed TargetFramework value to net6.0 from net5.0.

However, when I run "dotnet run," the app simply quits:

```
$ dotnet run
Building ...
$
```

This used to work fine earlier. The app would start running with "Press CTRL-C to quit" message. I could browse to my localhost to reach my personal website.

Suspecting some project setting incompatibility, I tried creating and running a new project:

```
$ mkdir mytest
$ cd mytest
$ dotnet new mvc
$ dotnet run
Building ...
$
```

Even the newly created app just quits.

Can someone please tell me how to fix my problem? Looks like something has changed in net6.0.

Update:

I solved my problem by going back to version 5.0.

Comment: what if you put dotnet build? I saw when it gives more detailed log information. And yes - a lot changed in how tools work in .net 6

Comment: Adding "dotnet build" did not do much unfortunately.

Comment: one thing to check (unless you already gave up, of course) is that 64-bit version of dotnet is on the path *before* 32-bit. That is, `Program Files` is before `Program Files(x86)`.  https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/11285 (and elsewhere) for more

Comment: Thanks. Mine is on Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Sorry - I missed it

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the details and maybe your problem is something else, but this solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69987329/12661819

> Add `<UseAppHost>false</UseAppHost>` under the `<PropertyGroup>` element of your project file.

Since I found your question first and it took me some time to dig up the solution I thought it might be a good idea to share it here.